# Number of days in year month

Tags: sql

I have tenure of employees in a database as a number of days. Is there any possibility to get it in the form of year and month like 2 year 5 months or 2.5 ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And define what you mean by month.

Comment: mention current sql as well

Comment: For Postgres: `select justify_days(interval '882 day')`

Comment: Does 2.5 literally refer to 2 years 5 months (i.e. 7 years 11 months would be 7.11) or are you creating a system that thinks years have 10 months?

Comment: 2.5 years isn't 2 years 5 monthes, but 2 years 6 monthes. 2 years 5 monthes is 2.4 years

Comment: @Cid: unless I'm badly misreading the question, according to OP 2.5 = 2 years 5 months. That would, of course, make comparisons between 2 years 5 months (2.5) and two years eleven months (2.11) awkward, but who am I to judge? :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis This may be the case, indeed, but this can lead easily to confusion/bugs. `2.5 + 2.5 = 5` or `4.10` ? and 4 years 10 monthes would be 4.1 -> `4 years 10 monthes == 4 years 1 month`

Comment: @Cid: OP should probably reconsider this. If dotted notation for years.months is desired then 2 years 5 months should probably be represented as 2.05, i.e. months should be 0.00, 0.01, 0.02, ... , 0.10, 0.11, 0.12. This obviously doesn't solve all issues (e.g. 2.07 + 2.08 = 4.15, requiring normalization of the months portion of the to get to 5.03), but it's something. IMO there shouldn't be a field containing tenure. I'd suggest that there should just be a field representing the hire date, with tenure being computed as needed from the hire date in whatever form is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As I correctly understood, in SQL Server you could achieve it in the following:

```
declare @noOfDays int = 890

select convert(decimal(10,1), datediff(day, dateadd(day, @noOfDays * -1, getdate()), getdate()) / 365.0)
```

Comment: It might be better to wait for the OP to tag a database system, rather than guess

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is rounded to one digit a simple arithmetic solution ignoring leap year could be used

Below is for MySql and is an integer division plus the fraction of the reminder

```
SELECT numberOfDays DIV 365 + ROUND((numberOfDays % 365) / 365, 1)
```

Of course this returns a numeric answer so 1 year and six months gets returned as 1.5

To get the decimal part as month fractions

```
SELECT numberOfDays DIV 365 + ROUND(1.2 * ((numberOfDays % 365) / 365), 1)
```